# How to use dialyzer with parse transform modules

Tags: erlang, dialyzer, parse-transform

I'm trying to use dialyzer on my erlang application but here's the output :

```
dialyzer \
        --src -r src \
        -pa /home/niahoo/src/popos \
        -pa /home/niahoo/src/popos/deps/parse_trans \
        --verbose
  Checking whether the PLT c:/MinGW/msys/1.0/home/niahoo/.dialyzer_plt is up-to-date... yes
  Proceeding with analysis...
dialyzer: Analysis failed with error:
Could not scan the following file(s): [{"c:/MinGW/msys/1.0/home/niahoo/src/popos/src/tools/r.erl",
                                        ["c:/MinGW/msys/1.0/home/niahoo/src/popos/src/tools/r.erl:none: undefined parse transform 'exprecs'\n"]},
                                       {"c:/MinGW/msys/1.0/home/niahoo/src/popos/src/game/party2.erl",
                                        ["c:/MinGW/msys/1.0/home/niahoo/src/popos/src/game/party2.erl:none: undefined parse transform 'playerdupli'\n"]}]
Last messages in the log cache:
  Reading files and computing callgraph...
```

I tried to put `playerdupli.erl` in the same directory as `party2.erl`, but the output is the same. `exprecs.erl` is in the deps: `deps/parse_trans/src`.

The code compiles and runs without error, including parse_transform stuff. I'm on MinGW (Windows 8 64). Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative that is always easier, is to compile with `+debug_info` and let dialyzer analyze the resulting `.beam` files.

Comment: Yeah this is what i did in the end. much more simple.

Answer (score 1):

So, i should have missed something in the doc. There is the command that works :

```
dialyzer \
    --src -r src \
    -pa /home/niahoo/src/popos \
    -pa ebin \
    -pa deps/parse_trans/ebin \
    --raw \
    --statistics \
```

`-pa /home/niahoo/src/popos` Allows dilayzer to find included .hrl used with include_lib
`-pa ebin` allows to find my parse_transform module (playerdupli)
`-pa deps/parse_trans/ebin` idem. with exprecs