# Erlang: run dialyzer on your whole application

Tags: erlang

I have an OTP application with the standard dir setup:

```
config/
log/
doc/
src/
_build/
rebar.config
```

I am able to run dialyzer on a src file like `dialyzer src/source_name.erl`. But this is kind of useless because function X in `src/foo1` may call a function Y in `src/foo2`, and you want to make sure X is passing the right type of argument to Y.

How do I use dialyzer to check all the interactions between function calls in my `/src` repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, the solution I found was to:

1. compile with +debug_info
2. recursively analyze the beam directory instead of the src directly

after compiling my command was

```
dialyzer -r _build/default/lib/myappname/ebin/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
dialyzer --src -r .
```

Or this:

```
dialyzer --src -r src
```

In order to recursively analyze the source code of your current directory or the src directory

Comment: when I tried this, I ran into another error, which said to solve that error, use .beam: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16723253/how-to-use-dialyzer-with-parse-transform-modules